# How to get the factors of a given number in Unix?

Tags: bash, functional-programming

I have this concern, when getting the factors of a number. My code gives me the total numbers of all factors of a number.What I want is it should only display the factors of that number, not the total. For example I input 9 the output should be 1,3 and 9.

My code

```
echo -n " enter a no. "
read n
i=1
mul=1
until [ $i -gt $n ]
do
mul=`expr $mul \* $i `
i=`expr $i + 1 `
done 
echo " factorial of $n is $mul "
```

Comment: Can you please help me?

Comment: It's recommended to use $( ... ) instead of ` ... ` these days.

Comment: P.S. if all you want are the prime factors, many Unixes have the command "factor", e.g. "factor 60".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the user enters the number in its simplest form, e.g. 9 instead of 09.0, this works:

```
echo -n " enter a no. "
read n
for i in $(seq 1 $n)
do
 [ $(expr $n / $i \* $i) == $n ] && echo $i
done
```

though a bit slowly for large numbers.

Comment: A quicker way would be to do seq to only the square root of n. For each factor i found, i and n / i are added to a buffer. The buffer is then sorted [with sort], duplicates (in case n is a square) removed [with uniq] and printed.

Comment: Don't use `expr` (or `==` inside `[...]`); `[ $(( n / i * i )) = $n ]`